# How to clean up brew doctor: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include?

Tags: homebrew, brew-doctor

Running "brew doctor".

> Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include. If
> you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
> building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

```
Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/allocation.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/common.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/custom-space.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/garbage-collected.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/heap.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/accessors.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/api-constants.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/compiler-specific.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/finalizer-trait.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/gc-info.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/logging.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/persistent-node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/pointer-policies.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/prefinalizer-handler.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/liveness-broker.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/macros.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/member.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/persistent.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/platform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/prefinalizer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/source-location.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/trace-trait.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/type-traits.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/visitor.h
  /usr/local/include/node/js_native_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/js_native_api_types.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform-export.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/v8-tracing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_api_types.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64le/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  .../*more lines that's past Stackoverflow's character limits*/
```

I researched and here's what I could find:

- Unbrewed files mean that these files were not added by Homebrew
  itself
- The issue seems to be with the Node.js package. If you don't
  use Node.js you can delete them without an issue.

And in another article,
It told me to follow those steps:

1. Simply run these four commands:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/include/node
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/bin
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/share
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/lib/dtrace
```

2. Finally, run the overwrite command:

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

What are this `chown` and `whoami`? And are the steps above correct in cleaning up the unbrewed header files?

Comment: You can simply ignore this warning.

Answer (score 1):

No, It doesn't clean the error if you do that!

Brew tell you to delete them if you didn't put them, but be careful before doing so, and I advice you to ignore it as @Zsigmond said.

Brew Said:

```
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
```

About your second question, here's my explanation:

`chown` it's abbreviation of "Change Owner", and it changes ownership of the folder.

`whoami` it's "Who am I?" and prints your username, so if your computer called 'Kristina' he will print that.

So, it means the folder `/usr/local/include/node` owner will be change to your username: `Kristina`, so you can have the privilege to control it.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the node helped me.
Here are steps on how to do it if you installed it without using homebrew:
https://dev.to/daud99/uninstall-node-on-mac-os-kmb