# What does this mean? Some installed kegs have no formulae

Tags: homebrew, brew-doctor

I see this after typing in "brew doctor"

> Warning: Some installed kegs have no formulae! This means they were
> either deleted or installed with `brew diy`. You should find
> replacements for the following formulae:
> python@2

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's just a warning, as most "brew doctor" messages are.  Python 2 is dead.  You can remove it with `brew uninstall python@2`.

Comment: Thanks! this fixed it. I tried to google `brew uninstall python@2` but couldn't find the answer I was looking for. If you have a moment, can you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973441/how-to-clean-up-brew-doctor-unbrewed-header-files-were-found-in-usr-local-incl please?